# Straight Lines; The area enclosed by |x| +|y| =1

Tags: area

Find the area enclosed by  the following graph :

$|x| +|y|=1 $

Comment: The question in the title doesn't match the question in the post. Also: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Though I think you meant the one in the title.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming  $|x|+|y|=1$

the straight lines are $x+y=1,x-y=1,-x-y=1,-x+y=1$

which form a square with each side $=\sqrt{(1-0)^2+(0-1)^2}$

or form four equal right isosceles triangles with each equal side $1$ unit

so, each has area $=\dfrac12\cdot1\cdot1$  sq. unit
Therefore area of area enclosed is 1/2 * 4 = 2 units